# NP-complete problem

Tags: np-complete, np

Is the following line true?

> Consider three problems A, B and C. If $A$ $<p$ $B$ and $B$ $<p$ $C$
> and $B$ is NP-complete problem, then $C$ is also NP-complete.

If B is NP-complete, then C would have also been NP-complete if it was in NP but it is not given here. Can we consider it false?
Or is there any other reason?

Comment: You are correct, all we know about $C$ is that it is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard. By the way, the fact that $A \leq^m_p B$ is irrelevant.